# Add Version/Flavor to Keys in Redis

Tags: redis

We are storing path's to data in redis as following:

```
KEY: `/pathOfUniqueAsset/v11/`
VALUE: `/disk1/pathOfUniqueAsset/path/v/11/`.
```

As you can see, the v which stands for version, will grow over time. I was wondering if there is a way to store `flavors`/`versions` of a key/value pair?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Hash instead of a String, as the key's value type. In the Hash, you can have a field per version/flavor and have the value as the associated path.

E.g.:

```
HSET /pathOfUniqueAsset v11 /disk1/pathOfUniqueAsset/path/v/11/
```

Comment: How would I query that than?

Comment: `HGET /pathOfUniqueAsset v11` to get a particular version. Or you can get `HKEYS /pathOfUniqueAsset` to get all versions and choose what to query.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? Do you need to keep older versions? If not, overwrite the key. If yes, what would 'version' of the key give you? You already know your version from the key. If you arrange your keys as pathOfUniqueAsset.v11, you can later issue `KEYS pathOfUniqueAsset.*` (or better `SCAN`) to get all versions. This way you can set `EXPIRE` individually. If you'll use `HSET` like @ItamarHaber suggests you can only delete values manually, but iterating a set is much faster than `KEYS` lookup (EDIT: actually, it depends on some factors, mostly the amount of other keys).

If you instead want a list of assets for each version kept together, you can use dedicated set of all keys associated to this version. Like

```
SET /pathOfUniqueAsset/v1 ...
HSET assets.v1 pathOfUniqueAsset /pathOfUniqueAsset/v1
```